# How to connect Excel table as database to RDLC? VB

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, rdl

My question is how to connect excel database to rdlc, lets say I have 2 columns with several rows,

```
A           B
Test1       Blah1
Test2       Blah2
```

And test1,test2, blah1,blah2 are their row values.. and my rdlc !Fields.Example.value contains "Test1_1"
and i want my rdlc to read the excel file, compare the values, and if the value is contained in rdlc file, then write the value from the column B.

I hope I said it right..

Thanks in advance. Is this possible to do?

Comment: I am guessing this is an Excel spreadsheet. You can get data from spreadsheets with ADO.net and the OleDb provider with Excel extension.

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot for your comment, is there any tutorial of how to connect such thing? maybe?, just asking

Comment: I googled "connection to Excel with ADO.net in vb.net". There are several. Stay away from ADODB because that is old technology. The goal would be to get the data into a DateTable. I know nothing about RDLC but I am sure it can talk to a DataTable.

Comment: Thank You a lot, Mary!!